# Deploying Multiple Angular Applications to Azure in same Angular Workspace

Tags: angular, angular6

My team is currently building a solution that has multiple Angular 6 aspects. The overall structure we are trying to achieve is two main applications: one client-facing portal and one admin facing site for administrators to perform CRUD operations on the client portal content. We want to be able to share global styles, basic services and components between the two angular apps.

Currently, we have three separate Angular workspaces: one for the client-facing portal, one for the admin CRUD site, and one for a shared library that the two main sites use to share components, importing it via NPM. The issue we run into is that changes in the shared library are difficult to test with two main applications. The current steps to show updated changes in the shared library are:

1. Build shared library after changes are made
2. Package the library to be exported as an NPM package
3. npm install to update the imported shared library in each of the main applications

We want to try to combine these three applications into a single workspace so that the shared library can be updated in the two main applications as changes are being made to it (most likely using `ng build shared-lib --watch`)

Mainly, we want to know if this is in fact possible. And if so, will this bring about issues when deploying if we want to deploy the two main applications to their own App services in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are doing is the correct workflow. Client and Admin app have a dependency on the npm package being built, so if that package updates you're always going to have to install the package to update it.

Having to manually update the packages is, as far as I am aware, a design of the npm ecosystem; you wouldn't want and older app with specific dependencies to update package versions on the fly and completely break.

This is a development environment scenario correct?

Comment: Yeah so I guess the question would be is there a better way to share material between two separate Angular apps the we would have to build and package every time we had a change?

Comment: Ohhh... I think I understand. Try giving the npm link functionality a shot. Here's a quick tutorial I found. https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-use-npm-link-7375b6219557 That might help alleviate your issues. The other option is trying to setup a lernajs environment.